# Get list default view url in SharePoint JSOM Client Object Model

Tags: client-object-model

I have simple JSOM script to get all the list and it's default view url but i am not getting default view url property

```
var context; 
var lists;

// This code runs when the DOM is ready and creates a context object which is needed  // to use the SharePoint object model $(document).ready(function () {

    context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    lists = context.get_web().get_lists();
    context.load(lists);
    context.executeQueryAsync(function () { reqSuccess(); }, function () { reqFail(); });
    });

function reqSuccess() {
    var listEnumerator = lists.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var list = listEnumerator.get_current();
        var listTitle = list.get_title();
        var listUrl = list.get_defaultViewUrl(); //Not getting this property
    } }

function reqFail(sender, args) {
    alert(args.get_message()); }
```

Answer (score 6):

The syntax for loading Default View URL is below.

```
context.load(lists,'Include(DefaultViewUrl)');
```

Default view is a valid list property and we need to explicitly load it.

Comment: you are right just but the syntax is little different context.load(lists, "Include(Title, DefaultViewUrl)");

Comment: Thansk @SandipPatil, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Since `List.DefaultViewUrl` property is not loaded by default you have to include it explicitly as demonstrated below:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var lists = context.get_web().get_lists();
context.load(lists,"Include(Title, DefaultViewUrl)");
context.executeQueryAsync(
  function () { 
    var e = lists.getEnumerator();
    while (e.moveNext()) {
        var list = e.get_current();
        var listTitle = list.get_title();
        var listUrl = list.get_defaultViewUrl(); 
        //...
    }
  },logError);


function logError(sender,args){
    console.log(args.get_message());
}
```